# ERROR: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'El índice -1 no tiene un valor.' C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

me estoy iniciando en la programación y tengo un problema al cargar una DataGridView, en el Load del formulario yo cargo la DGV con la lista de objetos que quiero mostrar, pero cuando agrego un nuevo objeto y vuelvo a poner en null y refrescar la DGV me salta el error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'El índice -1 no tiene un valor.'.

Si alguien le paso el mismo problema y lo pudo solucionar me ayudaría mucho con su respuesta!!

Código

Load

```
public frmPRINCIPAL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = null;
            dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = CProductos.ListaCompras;
        }
```

EventoAgregar

```
 private void btnAÑADIR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CProductos objetoAPasar = new CProductos();
            frmCOMPRAS nuevaCompra = new frmCOMPRAS(objetoAPasar);
            nuevaCompra.ShowDialog();
            dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = null;
            dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = CProductos.ListaCompras;
         }
```

luego en el otro formulario completo todas las propiedades del objeto y lo agrego a la lista y le devuevo el control al formulario frmPRINCIPAL

Aqui el codigo de la clase `CProductos`:

```
public class CProductos
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; }
    public static List<CProductos> ListaCompras = new List<CProductos>();
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Pasa un poco del codigo que tenes hecho asi te pueden ayudar

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el codigo de `CProductos`? El error debe estar al tratar el objeto `ListaCompras` que por lo que parece lo debes de haber declarado como estatico.

Answer (score 2):

Para comenzar, no debería tener una lista de `CProductos` dentro de `CProductos`. Recomiendo que hagas otra clase por ejemplo `CCarrito`, donde tenga la lista de `CProductos`.

Además, cada vez que llama a `CProducto.ListaCompras`, se esta haciendo un `new List<CProductos>` eliminando cualquier `CProductos` agregados a la lista.

Para evitar esto, `CCarrito` debe instanciar la lista de `CProductos` en el constructor:

Ejemplo:

```
public class CProductos
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; }
}

public class CCarrito
{
    public List<CProductos> ListaCompras { get; set; }

    public CCarrito 
    {
         ListaCompras = new List<CProductos>();
    }
}
```

El `CCarrito` podría por ejemplo ser instanciado en el `Form` principal.

Notar también que se cambia el DataSource a `CCarrito.ListaCompras`

```
private static CCarrito = null;

public frmPRINCIPAL()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CCarrito = new CCarrito();
    dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = null;
    dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = CCarrito.ListaCompras;
}

private void btnAÑADIR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CProductos objetoAPasar = new CProductos();
    frmCOMPRAS nuevaCompra = new frmCOMPRAS(objetoAPasar);
    nuevaCompra.ShowDialog();
    dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = null;
    dgvPRODUCTOS.DataSource = CCarrito.ListaCompras;
}
```